# Get topic branch from gerrit

Tags: git, branch, gerrit, repository

One developer pushed pack of patches to a gerrit under topic "test_topic". For example :)

I want to get all this patches on my development branch. Are there easy way to do this?
For now, I am using some magic, involving `gerrit query`, `grep`, `sort`, `awk` and then `git rebase -i`.

But, I am feeling, there are easy way. Possibly, using `repo` command. Nevertheless, I can't find this way,

Comment: Are the patches in question in different repositories but all the same topic branch name?  Or are they all in the same repository?

Comment: @Brad, yes, they are in same repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just pull down all the changes at once with the 'git pull' command you can copy-paste from Gerrit's web interface on the top-most change.  If you have local commits and don't want git to create a merge, look into the `--rebase` argument you can pass to git pull.

Comment: Great idea! I just missed, that `git fetch` will fetch entire change line, not the last commit. Thanks!

Comment: What if I want do it in script?